# Prove an inequality including sum of function series

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Defined on $(0,\infty)$, function $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x}{1+k^2x^2}$. Show the limit function $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ exsits for arbitraty $x>0$ and then show the inequality
$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x\leq f(x)\leq\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x+\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$

I met several problems here. First, it would be easier for me that $f_n(x)$ is $\frac{x}{1+n^2x^2}$, but when it comes to the summation of functions, I don't know how to find the limit as $n\to\infty$. Rewrite $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}u_{k}(x)$ where $u_k(x)=\frac{x}{1+k^2x^2}$, I only knew when $x=\frac{1}{k}$ the function $u_k(x)$ has maximum value of $\frac{1}{2k}$ but Weierstrass M-test cannot be applied. That's the first step I got confused.

About the inequality, I knew $\frac{\pi}{2}=\arctan x+\arctan \frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$. So it only needs to show
$$\arctan \frac{1}{x}\leq f(x)\leq\arctan\frac{1}{x}+\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$
So it comes back to the first step again, relating with limit function $f(x)$. How to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first question, you are asked to show a pointwise convergence.
Since your sequence is positive on $(0, \infty)$, you can apply a comapraison test. That is, you must find a sequence $v_k$ such that, for arbitrary $x>0$, you get that $\forall k \in \mathbb N ^*, 0\leq u_k(x) \leq v_k(x)$ and that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}v_k(x)$ exists.

Concerning the inequality, your rewriting seems correct, but I don't think it simplifies the problem : Here, we're comparing a series with an integral.

For arbitrary $x>0$, consider the function : $g_x(t) := \frac{x}{1+t^2x^2}$ on $(0, \infty)$. It's monotonous, isn't it?

It can therefore be enclosed in a frame on the interval $[k, k+1]$, for $k\in \mathbb N ^*$, like :

$$ \forall t \in [k, k+1], ~~\frac{x}{1+(k+1)^2x^2} \leq \frac{x}{1+t^2x^2} \leq \frac{x}{1+k^2x^2}$$

Now, you can take the integral from $k$ to $k+1$ (noting that $\int_{k}^{k+1}C\text{d}t = C$, if $C$ does not depend on t),

$$ \frac{x}{1+(k+1)^2x^2} \leq \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{x}{1+t^2x^2}\text{d}t \leq \frac{x}{1+k^2x^2}$$

Then, you can sum from $1$ to $n$,

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x}{1+(k+1)^2x^2} \leq \int_{1}^{n+1}\frac{x}{1+t^2x^2}\text{d}t \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x}{1+k^2x^2}$$

You'll recognize $f_n(x)$ and an integral that you can compute (something in arctan). Once you've calculated the integral, you'll be able to rewrite the inequality, then tend $n$ to $\infty$ to get the desired result.

Note that this method allows you to answer the first question, since by making $n$ tend towards $\infty$, you bound $f(x)$, and thus show the existence of a finite limit.

Comment: Good one, I derived the inequality without any difficulty.